# Custom boxshadow not showing

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte

I'm trying to add a custom shadow to my theme but it's not working, am I missing something?  I'm on Svelte. I also added colors which are working fine.

`tailwind.config.cjs`

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}'],
    theme: {
     colors: {
       'dark-purple':'#453F70',
       'darker-purple':'#353157',
       'light-purple':'#9B22DA',
       'medium-purple':'#6721DC',
     },
     extend: {
      boxShadow: {
        'neumorphic':"1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, -2px -2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) inset"
      }
    }
    },
    plugins: []
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is looking fine in `config file`.

You have to use the custom shadow like with this class `shadow-neumorphic`. Please verify this.

You can see the working code [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/PBhZTRj9gY)